# fgetcsv force file which is not utf-8 to be loaded as if it was?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, fgetcsv

I have a client which is not saving his CSV files in UTF 8, however when adding content, it has special chars which are UTF 8.

When I use fgetcsv and load it, forward it to MySql, it breaks with an error that content is not good.

When I save the file myself as UTF-8, all works like a charm.

Is there a way to mimic it without user having to save the file as UTF-8?

Thnx

Comment: Are you saying that the file contains some multi-byte utf8 characters and some other 8-bit characters?  (If so, that is really bad.)